# Equivalent of SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS NULL as rows, for SUM?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am currently using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS NULL as rows, as part of a complex join statement to get the total number of rows in a query based on search values that also contains a LIMIT.

Then I return the following.

```
     $response['total'] = $this->db->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() count;')->row()->count;
        $response['limit'] = $limit;
        $response['start'] = $start;
        $response['from'] = $start + 1;
        $response['to'] = $start + $query->num_rows();
        $response['count'] = $query->num_rows();
        $response['records'] = $query->result();
```

Here **Limit** might be 20, **start** might be 0, **total** is the full set of records for example 87 and **records** in the LIMIT set of records, eg 20.

Is there a way to also SUM one of my other fields  which holds dollar amounts, to get a total dollar amount for the entire set of (87) records, rather than the sub-set after the LIMIT gets applied?

Comment: No, that is not built into the database.  You can issue another query to calculate the `sum()`.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon for the quick response.  Based on your answer I split off the SELECT part of my query into a variable and then created a second select variable for the count(ids) as total_rows, SUM(profit) as total_profit, and ran a main query, then a second query for the two extra bits of data required